# Write a Spring batch custom item writer

Tags: spring-batch

I need to write a Spring batch custom item writer that uses a footer, but I can't use the delegate pattern.
Is there another way to write a Spring batch custom item writer?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've found the solution. I can't write a custom itemwriter, but I created a bean out and I have overridden the toString method. In this method I have set the output to the file as needed. Then, I created a PassThroughLineAggregator type itemwriter. This itemwriter calls the toString method of the bean output. And that's all!!

Here's the code:
MOH_Diaria_Bean_Out.java:

```
package es.lac.absis.batch.app.percai.domain;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MOH_Diaria_Bean_Out {
    List<MOH_Diaria_Bean> listaBeans = new ArrayList<MOH_Diaria_Bean>();

    public List<MOH_Diaria_Bean> getListaBeans() {
        return listaBeans;
    }

    public void setListaBeans(List<MOH_Diaria_Bean> listaBeans) {
        this.listaBeans = listaBeans;
    }

    public void add (MOH_Diaria_Bean bean){
        listaBeans.add(bean);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String salida="";
        for (int j=0; j<listaBeans.size(); j++) {
            MOH_Diaria_Bean bean = listaBeans.get(j);
            salida = salida + bean.toString();
            if (j<(listaBeans.size()-1)) {
                salida = salida + "\n";
            }       
        }
        return salida;
    }
}
```

ItemWriter:

```
<bean id="MOH_FusionadoFicheros_Writer" class="es.lac.absis.batch.arch.internal.writer.AbsisFlatFileItemWriter">
        <property name="resource">
            <bean class="es.lac.absis.batch.arch.internal.util.AbsisFileSystemResource"> 
                <constructor-arg ref="filePCA00020"></constructor-arg> 
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="encoding" value="ISO8859_1"></property> 
        <property name="lineAggregator">
            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.PassThroughLineAggregator">
            </bean>
        </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 5):

Create a custom `ItemWriter` that implements `ItemStream` (to manage restartability and footer writing) and overwrite the next methods:

- `ItemWrite.write(List<> items)`: write items and during writing perform necessary data calculation for footer
- `ItemStream.update(ExecutionContext)`: save calculated footer data in write() method
- `ItemStream.open(ExecutionContext)`: restore previously saved footer data
- `ItemStream.close()`: do real footer writing (directly in your own writer or using a callback)

Comment: Thank you bellabax, Could you tell me how to implement the corresponding bean?

Comment: Sorry, too much code to write; also I think this in not the real goal of SO: we can give you an idea, a code snippet or a bit more, not a full code implementation. If you can't use delegate pattern you have to write your "ItemWriter" from scratch; open file, manage real output stream,flush data, etc...use FlatFileItemWriter as template. Are you sure you can't use delegation/class extension?

Comment: Yes. I'm sure. Client architecture has a layer above Spring Batch and does not support Delegates.

Comment: an ItemWriterAdapter?

Comment: yw! Happy you found the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Check [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/patterns.html)

Basically you need to create a class that implements `ItemWriter<YourModel>` and `FlatFileFooterCallback`

In the `write` method, enter how data will be written and in the `writeFooter` the footer of the file.
Then declare your class as a bean and put it as a writer in your job.

Comment: Thank you dimzak. The link you've provided uses delegate pattern. I can't use this pattern.

Comment: I looked at implementing own writer and overriding writeHeader(), but for that to work i need to know the column names before hand and since am working on a generic export i can't do that here.Is there an easy way to achieve this?